# Partial Differential Equations with boudary conditions (using method of characteristics)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Given the PDEs

$$u_{xx}+u_{xy}-2u_{yy}=0$$

$$u_{xx}-2u_{xy}+2u_{yy}=0$$

and

$$u_{xx}+3u_{xy}+2u_{yy}=0$$

and the boundary conditions:

$$ u(t,t)=sin(t), \ \frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial x} \big |_{x=t}-\frac{\partial u(t,y)}{\partial y} \big |_{y=t}=t$$

$$ u(t,-t)=sin(t), \ \frac{\partial u(x,-t)}{\partial x} \big |_{x=t}+ \frac{\partial u(t,y)}{\partial y} \big |_{y=-t}=t$$

$$u(cos(\theta),sin(\theta)=sin(2\theta)$$

The first PDE with $A=1, B=1/2$ and $C=-2$ is a hyperbolic PDE with the general solution of the form $\phi_1 = f(y-2x)+g(y+x)$

The second PDE with $A=1, B=-1$ and $C=2$ is an elliptic PDE since it cannot be factored like in equation 1 and simply calculate the two ODEs, I haven't calculated its general solution (i know how to bring it into normal form and calculate the general solution that way but that's not the point of this post so i leave it for now)

The third PDE with $A=1, B=1.5$ and $C=2$ is again a hypebolic PDE with general solution $\phi_1 = f(y-x)+g(y-2x)$

According to the book i'm using if the type of equation is **hyperbolic**, then we use the **Cauchy condition**, if the equation is **elliptic** then we use **Dirichlet** or **Neumann** condition.

My question is, can we always apply this rule? And in that case I can assign condition 1 or 2 to the equations 1 and 3 and condition 3 to equation 2?

And there is something else i don't understand (after reading about 20 PDFs on it). When it comes to the methods of characteristics and quote:

> For second-order PDEs we might expect that relevant boundary conditions would involve specifying $u$, or some of its fist derivatives, or both, along a suitable set of boundaries bordering or enclosing the region over which a solution is sought. The characteristics of second-order PDEs can be considered as the curves along which partial information about the solution $u(x,y)$ "propagates". Blahblahblah

I understand this part, so basically the solution curve needs to "cut" these characteristics exactly once for the solution to be "well-posed".

But how do I know if the solution curve cuts the characteristic lines, and how do i know if it cuts it only once or multiple times (without the help of a computer to model it)?

Appreciate any help!